# PDFPage's "setBounds" not crop the annotations applied to pdfpage

Tags: swift, pdf, ios-pdfkit

I am setting bounds of pdfpage to crop the page. it crop the page but not the annotations applied to it.

```
page.setBounds(rect, for: .cropBox)
```

by this code annotation applied to page will show over the cropped page as in image

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is standard behavior, annotations are not cropped by CropBox, only the page content is.

Comment: can we restrict annotation to not to show out from setbound pdfpage ?

Comment: @spanixdev no, You cannot